# What does different conditional mean

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Could someone explain the difference in the meaning between these:

$$E(X|Y)$$

$$E(X|Y=y)$$

$$E(X|y)$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/872278/321264

Answer (score 1):

Here are some:

- The mathematical object E[X|Y] is a random variable, it exists as soon as X and Y are defined on the same probability space and X is integrable.
- The mathematical object E[X|Y=y] is a number, it exists as soon as X and Y are defined on the same probability space and [Y=y] has positive probability.
- The mathematical object E[X|y] does not exist.

Comment: Thank you. Why E[X|Y] is a random variable? It looks like I calculate $E[X|Y=y_i]$ for all $y_i$ and, then, combine it into a vector. No?

Comment: @Mrclause, because it's a function of the sample space, namely the function $\omega\mapsto \mathbb{E}(X\mid Y=Y(\omega))$. Did, I suspect $\mathbb{E}(X\mid y)$ is a notation for $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y=y)$.

Comment: @JonathanY. Sure it is, and as such it should be eliminated.

Comment: @JonathanY. But $E(X|Y=y)$ is also function of the sample space. We redo our experiment and get new $\omega$ and, as a result, new y.

Comment: @Mrclause No, E[X|Y=y] is a number, just like E[X]. Would you say one gets a new "result" E[X] each time one does a new experiment?

Answer (score 1):

One way to see it is the following: We know by a "fundamental lemma" of probability 
(or rather measure theory) that any $\sigma(Y)$-measurable function can be represented as a function of $Y$. This is the case for the conditional expectation and thus
$$ E(X | Y) = f(Y) $$
With this in mind we can **define** the conditional expectation in a point as
$$ E(X | Y = y) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} f(y) $$

Then we have that if $\mu$ is the law of $Y$ we have that this newly defined function satisfies
$$ E(X) = E( E(X | Y ) ) = E(f(Y)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) \,  \mu(dy) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} E(X | Y = y) \, \mu(dy) $$

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your comparison. It seems like you just replace Y with y.

Comment: @Mrclause: If you accept that $E[X|Y=y]$ is a function of $y$ called $f(y)$ which may vary with $y$, then $E[X|Y]$ is a random variable which can be written $f(Y)$: if $Y=y$ then $f(Y)=f(y)$

Comment: Indeed, we *define* the function "$E(X | Y = y)$". Check the further development I added to the response.

Comment: One can define $E[X|Y=y]$ as $f(y)$ only when $f(y)$ is nonambiguous, that is, if and only if $P[Y=y]\ne0$. Otherwise, $f(y)$ can be *anything*.

Comment: You mean we should keep in mind that these are class of equivalences of functions? We could pick some element of the class to define it. 

Indeed in the discrete case this is trivial.

Comment: If you have some possibly correlated variables $(X,Y)$ with density $d$ you can indeed define $E(X | Y = y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x d(x,y) dx$ and the function "f" on the example will be its class of equivalence up to measure zero.