# What is the exact relationship between $E(Y\mid X=x)$ and $E(Y\mid X)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, density-function

I know that $E(Y\mid X)$ is a random variable of $X$, while $E(Y\mid X=x)$ is a value. However, when they both appear in a problem like the one below, I cannot tell the exact relationship between them.

---

Problem:

Assume that $(X,Y)$ has a jointly probability density function

$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{21}{4}x^2y, & \text{if } x^2 \le y \le 1, \\ 
0, & \text{else}.
\end{cases}$$

(1) Show the probability density function of $X$, i.e. $f_X(x)$;

(2) Fixed $x\in (-1,1)$, show the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X=x$, i.e. $E(Y\mid X=x)$;

(3) Show $E(Y|X)$.

---

I have finished the first 2 subproblems:

(1) $\displaystyle
f_X(x)
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)\,dy
=\ldots
=\begin{cases}
\frac{21}{8}x^2(1-x^4), & \text{if } x^2 \le 1,\\ 
0, & \text{else}.
\end{cases}$

(2) $\displaystyle
f_{Y|X=x}(y|x)
=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}
=\begin{cases}
\frac{2y}{1-x^4}, & \text{if } x^2 \le y \le 1 \text{ and } x \in (-1,0)\cup(0,1),\\ 
0, & \text{else}.
\end{cases}$

### $E(Y\mid X=x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}yf_{Y\mid X=x}(y\mid x)dy=\cdots=\frac{2}{3}\frac{1+x+x^2}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}, x\in (-1,0)\cup(0,1)$

I'm confused with **the relationship between $E(Y\mid X=x)$ and $E(Y \mid X)$**, especially when the definition domain is something like the things here.

Also, though I finished the subproblem (2), I still cannot understand how the $x=0$ disappears and **what the meaning behind it is**.

---

Please help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: $\mathbf{E}[Y\mid X]$ is a random variable whose value is $\mathbf{E}[Y\mid X=x]$ whenever $\{X=x\}$ holds. Equivalently, if we write $h(x)=\mathbf{E}[Y\mid X=x]$, then $\mathbf{E}[Y\mid X]=h(X)$. In particular, if $X$ takes only countably many values, say $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots$, then $$\mathbf{E}[Y\mid X]=\sum_{k}\mathbf{E}[Y\mid X=x_k] \mathbf{1}_{\{X=x_k\}}.$$

Comment: As for 2), you need to integrate over y. You have the conditional probability density over Y when X is known. This is not the expectation. As for 3, maybe they want you to draw the function E[Y|X=x] . Not very clear for me neither...

Comment: For your second question, the case $x=0$ is excluded just because we don't want to run into the division-by-zero issue over the course of the computation. However, since $X$ has a continuous distribution, the particular value of $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid 0)$ is irrelevant; you can freely modify its value and still get a valid answer.

Comment: @ArnaudMégret: Ah! I forgot to post my result of $E(Y\mid X=x)$, actually I have calculated that...

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you for your explanation, but what is the meaning of the description "irrelevant" here?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/872278/321264